# Mac Pro says RAID degraded but all drives showing green status

Tags: raid, mac-osx-server, hardware-raid, degraded

OSX 10.9 - 
RAID Utility says RAID array is degraded but all drives are showing green

All started after error log

> Drive 3:5000c5004e189ddf missing - Previous drive status was inuse

Now getting errors daily saying

> Degraded RAID set RS1 - No spare available for rebuild

Looking at each drive separately all say "Assigned" except Bay 1 which says "Roaming"

Comment: And what have you found "roaming" to mean in your searches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After ignoring the "Drive 3:blahblah"
I removed the Drive in Bay 1 that showed status as "roaming" and booted. 
Since the Mac still booted I was sure that drive was the issue.

I put a new drive in and selected it in RAID utility - Selected "RAID" from the Mac top menu and clicked "mark as spare" and assigned it to my RAID set.

RAID rebuild like a champ!